# EF6 calling stored procedure with parameters not running?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, oracle11g

I'm struggling to get an Oracle stored procedure to run with some return values. I think I'm getting close but I'm getting the following error:

> When executing a command, parameters must be exclusively database parameters or values.

I will say I've never used EF to call a stored procedure with output parameters, so I'm sure I have something set incorrectly but it looks a though the code should work.

```
using (var ctx = new DataContext())
{
    DateTime shiftStartDate = DateTime.Parse(startDateTime);
    DateTime shiftEndDate = DateTime.Parse(endDateTime);

    var empId = new OracleParameter("empId", OracleDbType.Varchar2, employeeId, ParameterDirection.Input);
    var startDate = new OracleParameter("startDate", OracleDbType.Date, shiftStartDate, ParameterDirection.Input);
    var endDate = new OracleParameter("endDate", OracleDbType.Date, shiftEndDate, ParameterDirection.Input);
    var swapEmpId = new OracleParameter("swapEmpId", OracleDbType.Varchar2, swapEmployeeId, ParameterDirection.Input);
    var IsValid = new OracleParameter("Valid", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
    var Remarks = new OracleParameter("Remarks", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);

    var results = ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("VALIDATE_CS_POLICY  :empId, :startDate, :endDate, :swapEmpId, :Valid, :Remarks", employeeId, startDateTime, endDateTime, swapEmployeeId, IsValid, Remarks);

    string resultIsValid = IsValid.Value.ToString();
    string resultRemarks = Remarks.Value.ToString();
}
```

This is what I was given as the stored procedure declaration

```
PROCEDURE SCHEMANAME.VALIDATE_CS_POLICY (EMPID CHAR, CS_START DATE, CS_END DATE, SWAP_EMPID CHAR, VALID OUT CHAR, REMARKS OUT VARCHAR)
```

Comment: `outParam.ParameterDirection = ParameterDirection.Output;` perhaps

Comment: Thanks, I changed that and still the same error. I actually had used Output the first time and then found the ReturnValue in a post and thought I would give it a try...but that didn't work either. This is what I tried var Remarks = new OracleParameter("Remarks", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);

Comment: Not 100% sure here but also `var results = ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("VALIDATE_CS_POLICY  :empId, :startDate, :endDate, :swapEmpId, :Valid, :Remarks", employeeId, startDateTime, endDateTime, swapEmployeeId, IsValid, Remarks).ToList();` to force it to realize the results?

Comment: Not sure if Oracle is picky about the parameter *names* - but your stored procedure has e.g. a parameter `CS_START`, but in your C# code, you define a parameter with a name of `StartDate` - maybe you should try using the actual and exact parameter names from the stored procedure definition

Comment: for the input parameters, try just putting the field name and value, for example var empId = new OracleParameter("empId", employeeId);

Comment: It might also be that `var policy = results.Single();` would be better than `.ToList()`, here. (before attempt to access the parameters values)

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I've tried all of these and still didn't get it to work. I will also say that I've tried Database.SqlQuery and .FirstOrDefault() with no luck. Manager wants to go back to using straight ADO.Net because of course everything is due yesterday. I think the biggest issue is that it's using the output parameters and not just returning a result set. Trying to come up with a different approach but still using EF if possible but I might have to throw in the towel on this one if I don't come up with something in the next hour or so.

Comment: There's no value in the EF wrappers here.  But  you don't have to abandon EF where it makes sense.  In this method drop down to ADO.NET, and in other methods use the DbContext.

Comment: We did a semi hack for the moment because it had a deadline. We created a function that would call the SP. The function returned a result set and not output parameters so it worked just fine with EF. I'm now going to go back and use regular ADO.Net to call the Stored Proc so we can get rid of the function. Thanks for everyone that gave suggestions though.

Comment: When you are calling the stored proc, shouldnt you put brackets around the call? `ExecuteSqlCommand("VALIDATE_CS_POLICY ( :empId, :startDate, etc )`?  Also those `ReturnValues` should be `Output`.